# regression wtith t scores

Tags: regression, linear, z-score

I have performed a study in which I converted performance on a cognitive test to z statistics and from that derived t scores. We would like to examine the relationship between t-scores and various demographic variables. Is it appropriate to conduct linear regression using t-scores as the dependent variable?

Comment: "Appropriate" for what purpose?  What do you hope to accomplish and how do you think you would interpret the results?

Comment: Adding to @whuber 's comment (+1) you should consider audience. While there's nothing really *wrong* with doing regression on t scores, they are, I think, pretty unfamiliar and may generate confusion with t statistics (results of a t test) as opposed to t scores (mean 50 sd 10).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. By appropriate, my feeling was percentage or percentile data does not meet the criteria for which a regression expression can be correctly applied or interpreted.